# Maven osgi.bundle dependency missing

Tags: maven, osgi, maven-3, osgi-bundle

I am trying to build maven package and get a error:
Missing requirement: org.talend.designer.codegen 8.8.8.qualifier requires 'osgi.bundle; org.talend.repository 0.0.0' but it could not be found

But OK, org.talend.repository is another package in the parent directory.
But all my maven compilations was failed on "osgi.bundle" dependency.
Where can I get this dependency and how can I install it.

Comment: Can you share the content of the maven pom?

Comment: I tryind to build Talend Open Studio from here: https://github.com/Talend/studio-se-master.

Comment: This build looks strange to me. The main pom seems to reference modules outside of the checkout path. Maybe you need to correct versions of these modules.
Also the build is an eclipse tycho build which I am not very familiar with.